# AngularJS - Returning 100k rows with 200 characters in each

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

I have a web page control panel that returns different data sets depending on which page you are looking at. These data sets can vary greatly in size, from a couple thousand to up to a million. While it is unreasonable to think someone to look at a million rows in a table I have to make it work and am unsure of the best way to go about it.

I make a `$http.get` request and all the data is returned however is it possible for it to all be done of the server side as it takes about a minute to load? I read that `angular-datatables` should be able to do this but I can't find any working JSFiddles of it. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Please add *why* you want this, as this is quite unconventional, maybe we can suggest a better technique alltogether

Comment: When you need the data for tables, I recommend using [AG Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/best-angularjs-data-grid/), It can handle both 100k rows client side *and* it can fetch data from a server for pagination and searching.

Comment: Updated the post @Martijn

Comment: Based on your edit: Just make a prev/next page system and limit it to e.g. 100 rows at a time. Your system, your rules.

Comment: let your backend use some kind of paging construction, for example by implementing parameters like offset and limit